# build a non binary tree, every node has large number of children in c++

Tags: c++, tree, structure

i need to build a tree with c++, where the 1st level of it has m nodes,every node of m nodes has m-1 children, so the 2nd level would have m*(m-1) nodes, the 3rd level would have m*(m-2) nodes, and so on. (similar to the attached img).
how can i declare every child node and add this huge number of children for every node in each level? can i do it recursively?
we can assume for a start that m is a small number, m<=20.

i know this is extremely large load for the memory but while we proceed deeper in every level the number for children will be reduced according to some conditions applied before adding a new child,so mainly just level 1 & 2 will add the full number of nodes.

[tree](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eyLqU.png)

Comment: Have you considered using a `std::vector`?

Comment: not clear what the question is exactly, if you know how to add 2 you almost have everything you need to add `n`. Instead of `left` and `right` pointers maybe a vector of child node pointers. Tbh your concerns about memory are a bit strange, because it makes little difference if you have 1million nodes in a binary tree or in a non-binary tree, memory footprint is almost the same

Comment: Your tree will have N = m*(m-1)*..*2.1 elements, while m = 13, N = 6.227.020.800 elements, m = 20 would cause a big memory problem for you.

Comment: Search the internet for "C++ B-Tree" or "C++ B*Tree".  Or "C++ tree pages".  Your data structure is in the Data Structure text books, so you should be able to find an example on the web.

Answer (score 4):

If you know the size at compile time, use a recursive template:

```
#include <array>

template <int N>
class Foo
{
    std::array<Foo<N-1>, N> children;
};

template<>
class Foo<0>
{
};

int main()
{
    Foo<4> bar;
}
```

Otherwise, use a vector:

```
#include <vector>

class Foo
{
    std::vector<Foo> children;
    public:
        Foo(int N)
        :children(std::max(0, N-1), Foo(N-1)){} // Infinite recursion here, you will need to handle this case
};

int main()
{
    Foo bar(4);
}
```